# How to crop image based on the object radius using OpenCV?

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing

I'm new to python. I know basics about image-preprocessing. I don't know how to remove background and crop an image using OpenCV.

[image: image1]

Comment: Threshold followed by masking should do the trick

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the processing in Python/OpenCV for your new image.

Input:

[image]

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

# load image as grayscale
img = cv2.imread('Diabetic-Retinopathy_G_RM_151064169.jpg')

gray = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

# threshold input image
mask = cv2.threshold(gray, 10, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY)[1]

# optional morphology to clean up small spots
kernel = cv2.getStructuringElement(cv2.MORPH_ELLIPSE, (3,3))
mask = cv2.morphologyEx(mask, cv2.MORPH_CLOSE, kernel)
mask = cv2.morphologyEx(mask, cv2.MORPH_OPEN, kernel)

# put mask into alpha channel of image
result = np.dstack((img, mask))

# save resulting masked image
cv2.imwrite('Diabetic-Retinopathy_G_RM_151064169_masked.png', result)

# display result, though it won't show transparency
cv2.imshow("mask", mask)
cv2.imshow("RESULT", result)
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

[Result](http://www.fmwconcepts.com/misc_tests/Diabetic-Retinopathy_G_RM_151064169_masked.png)

Answer (score 0):

Here is one way to do that in Python/OpenCV.

- Read input
- Convert to grayscale
- Threshold and invert as mask
- Put mask into alpha channel of input
- Save result

Input:

[image]

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

# load image
img = cv2.imread('black_circle.png')

# convert to grayscale
gray = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

# threshold
threshold = cv2.threshold(gray,128,255,cv2.THRESH_BINARY)[1]

# invert so circle is white on black
mask = 255 - threshold

# put mask into alpha channel of image
result = np.dstack((img, mask))

# save resulting masked image
cv2.imwrite('black_circle_masked.png', result)

# display result, though it won't show transparency
cv2.imshow("MASK", mask)
cv2.imshow("RESULT", result)
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Result:

[image]

Note: download the result to see the transparency.

Comment: Hey thanks for the help. I have different type of images. just for sample purpose i have used above images. Sorry for incorrect details. here is the image : https://www.ophthalmologyadvisor.com/wp-content/uploads/sites/24/2021/07/Diabetic-Retinopathy_G_RM_151064169.jpg . I have many eye images of different sizes. I want to remove background and crop the image based on the circle. Can you please help me with that? Thanks in advance.

Comment: See my new answer to address that type image. Adjust the threshold as needed for the black level or try Otsu thresholding or cv2.inRange() for a range of black and then invert so the background is black and the masked area is white.

Comment: okay will do that thanks for the help and also can you help me with this problem : 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71818988/is-my-confusion-matrix-is-showing-differently-or-is-it-correctly-showing?noredirect=1#comment126914327_71818988

Comment: Sorry, I do not know much about those tools.